# Trying to regex for strings longer than 22 characters

Tags: regex

I have a very long array of data, and I need to quickly whizz through it and make sure that none of the **names** are longer than 22 characters. I understand that I could truncate it on the display side, but I would rather tackle this with a proper solution, of just removing them :)

This is my sample

```
$profiles[257] = array('name'=>'FedupKissingFrogs', 'age'=>27, 'sex'=>'F', 'location'=>'XXXXXXXXXX');
$profiles[260] = array('name'=>'Lil_Greta_90', 'age'=>20, 'sex'=>'F', 'location'=>'XXXXXXXXXX');
$profiles[262] = array('name'=>'lOOkfOrme86', 'age'=>24, 'sex'=>'F', 'location'=>'XXXXXXXXXX');
$profiles[259] = array('name'=>'youvefoundME', 'age'=>21, 'sex'=>'F', 'location'=>'XXXXXXXXXX');
```

And here is the regex that I have come up with so far, which doesn't seem to work at all

```
'[A-Za-z]{20,40}'
```

My plan is that I can use the regex to mark the lines and then I can delete them from within my IDE. There is no programming allowed ;)

-- Edit --

Thanks for all the replies! The idea behind this was a quick and automated way to just scan a flat PHP file containing an array to see if all the names where shorter than 22 characters, as a name longer than that will break the layout, and I've been asked to remove them. I wanted to just search in my IDE and remove the lines.

Matching the characters isn't important as such, any characters are allowable, even space, \ / ~ and * etc. I'm looking more to match length of the string but contained in the `=>'$name'` container.

Comment: What language/framework are you using? Surely there's something built-in that will allow you to test a string's length without resorting to a regex?

Comment: @Luke: it doesn't seem to be just string length issue.

Comment: Why `{20,40}` if you want strings of length `<=` 22?

Comment: @SilentGhost: The question says *"make sure that none of the names are longer than 22 characters"* which sounds like a string length issue to me, although the question is a bit vague. David should clarify the requirements.

Comment: @Luke: yes and regex shows that OP's checking for specific characters.

Comment: So which IDE you're using then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The regex would be:

```
/'name'=>'[^']{23,}?'/i
```

This will match any line with a 'name' that is 23 characters or longer.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, I shall save this somewhere special for future use :)

Answer (score 53):

This will match "At least 22 any characters"

```
.{22,}
```

Comment: So as soon as the file gets 22 character long or longer, then this will match... the whole file.

Comment: Why? did you try this? It should match line-by-line

Comment: +1 Contrary to Lazarus' solution, this works just fine.

Comment: This would be the best answer

Answer (score 4):

This regex will match a string longer than 22 chars

```
/.{23,}/
```

Comment: So as soon as the file gets 22 character long or longer, then this will match... the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resist using the good ol' `strlen`.

```
foreach ($profiles as $id => $data) {
    if (strlen($data['name']) >= 22)
        unset($profiles[$id]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not processing the file, it's flat. Therefore it's not possible to parse the array using PHP. I'm looking for a regex solution to allow me to apply a similar technique in the future :)

Comment: regex is better way instead of fucntion