# validation textbox atlease entre more than 50 word

Tags: validation

the validation using regularexpression, what is the expression?
my validation expression no work, hwo to correct it bu do not count the space

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="MUST MORE THAN 50 WORD"  Text="*" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression='"^(\b\S+\b\s*){0,10}$"' ControlToValidate="txtWrite"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if you want word characters more than 50 in your textbox:

```
'"^(\w{50,})$"'
```

instead of:

```
'"^(\b\S+\b\s*){0,10}$"'
```

Also this link can be of some help to you:

[Trying to regex for strings longer than 22 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735164/trying-to-regex-for-strings-longer-than-22-characters)